# this `implicitly` has type any it does not have type annotation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

i am calling function `this.buildSingleRequestBody` it is throwing error this implicilty has type any it does not have type annotation , not sure what has implemented wrong.

main.ts

```
 private  buildRequestArray(specialtyMembers: ISpecialtyInfoObj[],
                               request: ICombinedAccountBalanceRequest): IRequestURL[] {
        const specialtyUrl = urlConfig.specialtyBaseUrl + "payments/getAccountBalance";

        const serviceContext = request.header.serviceContext;
        const requestArray: IRequestURL[] = specialtyMembers.map(function(member) {
            const body: any = this.buildSingleRequestBody(member, serviceContext);
            return {url: specialtyUrl, body};
        });

        return requestArray;
    }


   private buildSingleRequestBody(specialtyMember: ISpecialtyInfoObj, serviceContext: IServiceContext) {
        return {
            "header": {
                serviceContext
            },
            "specialtyId": specialtyMember.Id || "78988716",
            "specialtySource": specialtyMember.specialtySource || "HBS"
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`function` does not capture `this` from the declaration context, rather `this` is decided by the caller. Since you use `function` when you call `map`, the `this` inside anonymous function will not refer to the class.  Since `map` does not explicitly declare what `this` it will pass into the function, the type of `this` will implicitly be any inside the anonymous function, hence the error.

Use an arrow function instead as that will capture the declaration `this`

```
private  buildRequestArray(specialtyMembers: ISpecialtyInfoObj[],
                           request: ICombinedAccountBalanceRequest): IRequestURL[] {
    const specialtyUrl = urlConfig.specialtyBaseUrl + "payments/getAccountBalance";

    const serviceContext = request.header.serviceContext;
    const requestArray: IRequestURL[] = specialtyMembers.map((member) => {
        const body: any = this.buildSingleRequestBody(member, serviceContext);
        return {url: specialtyUrl, body};
    });

    return requestArray;
}


private buildSingleRequestBody(specialtyMember: ISpecialtyInfoObj, serviceContext: IServiceContext) {
    return {
        "header": {
            serviceContext
        },
        "specialtyId": specialtyMember.Id || "78988716",
        "specialtySource": specialtyMember.specialtySource || "HBS"
    };
}
```

Comment: what if my desired function is for this not to be captured but I want this to be different than the class in javascript you can easily do this and if Typescript is just a super set of Javascript shouldn't I be able to also do this is in TypeScript?

Comment: @BoxandCox Depends what you are trying to do, using a regular `function` or method will result in this not being captures. You can also  annotate what the type of this for a function will be for a function (ex: `function (this: SomeType)`) although that is not always needed. I would need an example of what you are doing to offer more suggestions